# Gemfile specify ruby-1.9.3, bundle install asks for ruby-2.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm developing two different projects: one using ruby-1.9.3 and another using ruby-2.0.0 (the version of Rails changes too). I was developing the 2º project and now I'm coming back to the 1º (ruby 1.9.3), but I'm having some troubles.

Before start explain my problem, this is the result when I run `rvm list`:

```
rvm rubies

=> ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ i686 ]
 * ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

**If I run `ruby -v` I got:**

```
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [i686-linux]
```

**And you can find in my gemfile of the first project:**

```
ruby '1.9.3'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
```

---

**My problem is:** I can't run the server and download/install the gems. When I try to run `rails s` in my first project I get:

```
Could not find rake-10.1.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

**And when I try to run `sudo bundle install` I get:**

```
Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
```

But you saw above that my gemfile specify 'ruby-1.9.3', not 'ruby-2.0.0'. What can I do to start work hard in my old project?

Comment: Are you using `rvm gemsets`? I highly recommend using a gemset for every project. Example:`rvm gemset create project1`, `rvm gemset use project1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that there is some conflict between the native ruby installation and the RVM installation.

I recommend you try this:

```
$ cd /path/to/ruby-1.9.3/project1
$ rvm use 1.9.3
$ rvm gemset create project1
$ rvm gemset use project1
$ bundle install
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip. For my other project, I need just create another gemset so use the correspondent gemset? I'm trying what you told, and this seems to work (installing gems now). The strange is, when I run `sudo bundle install`, this shows me "Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3". If I just run `bundle install`, this apparently works (as I said, this is installing gems now).

Comment: I'm guessing that sudo is checking against the root user, which may be using ruby 2, and not sudo'ing uses your user, which is currently set to use 1.9.3, but i could be wrong on that.

Comment: I think it's working. It's still installing gems, when I finish I come here to post the result (:

Comment: @FernandoPaladini: afaik rvm should not be used with sudo, you have rvmsudo if you really want to do so, consider adding `.ruby-gemset` (with eg. `my_gemset` string) and `.ruby-version` (with eg. `ruby-1.9.3-p484`) files so you will switch automatically ruby's version and use proper gemset when entering directory.

Comment: Thnaks @Catfish , this solved my problem! Thanks for your answer too zrl3dx!